# Can I sell a mobile app that contains definitions from a GPL licensed dictionary?

Tags: united-states, software, open-source-software

I am developing a mobile word game in which the word list and word definitions come from the [GCIDE Dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GCIDE). According to my research this software is released under the GNU General Public License.

I am not using the dictionary's software, only the words and definitions that the software uses, which are originally compiled from other dictionaries (1913 Webster, WordNet, etc). I downloaded the word list separate from the application and copied it to my own formatted file.

My research on the license has led to a lot of concern with this:

Is this considered using/distributing the licensed dictionary software?

Am I able to sell my mobile game without releasing the source code to the public?

If I sell my mobile game, are purchasers able to redistribute my software freely since the dictionary is under a free license?

I want to avoid any future problems with this, so any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GCIDE dictionary itself is licensed under GPL-3.0. It consists of a bunch of files with markup, no software involved. Indeed, the GPL can also be applied to non-software works, though it is unusual.

When you use material under some license, you must comply with the terms of the license. In case of the GPL, there are two highly relevant conditions:

- Everyone who receives a copy of the covered work (original or modified, in whole or in part) must receive the complete corresponding source code of the work, under the terms of the GPL-3.0.
- If you create a derivative work of the covered work, the derivative work can only be distributed under the GPL-3.0.

However, *selling* the covered material is perfectly fine. The GPL does not forbid you to make money, however you must not profit from your requirement to provide the corresponding source code.

Here, the core question is whether your mobile game would be a derivative work of the GPL-licensed dictionary. If your game merely loads the dictionary as a data file, I don't think they would form a single derived work. However, if you compile the dictionary into your app, this would be more difficult to argue.

Ultimately, what is a derivative work will depend on a court. It could therefore be helpful to keep your app as clearly non-derivative as possible. I would avoid baking the dictionary into the app's binary but store it separately as a data file, would show attribution notices in reasonable places (e.g. a screen with attribution notices and the complete license text), and would make it possible for users to export a copy of the dictionary files. Furthermore, the GPL-3.0 may require you to allow users to modify this file, for example by making it possible to import a modified dictionary into your app.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough response! This helps a lot.

Comment: Minor issue: "must receive the complete corresponding source code of the work" is not quite correct. They must receive the source code *or an offer to give it to them*.

Comment: The GPL permits aggregation, so as long as you read the dictionary file at run time there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks Paul, this really eases my concern. I will be using the dictionary as a separate data file and read it to memory at run time to avoid it being part of my build. You all are life savers.

Comment: @DrewK I do not believe that is a valid legal test, actually - I believe amon is wrong here. The dictionary is still part of your app, no?

Comment: @user253751 Could you explain what aspect I've gotten wrong? My reasoning is that using a software to process some data does not make the software derivative of the data. Thus, I'm recommending that OP keep a clear software–data split and comply with the license with respect to the data. OP's suggestion to “avoid [the dictionary] being part of my build” may or may not be relevant.

Comment: @amon AFAIK, if you embed the data in the software then it is now part of the software. If you make an app that can open .dictionary files in general, then it's obviously not derivative of the dictionary file, but if you make one that opens a .dictionary file it *comes with*, what you are selling is a "bundle" containing some code and a dictionary, and that bundle is obviously derivative of the dictionary, and therefore restricted by its license.

Comment: You could avoid this by having two separate downloads (so the app can read any dictionary and the dictionary can be read by any app). (Standard disclaimer: I am not a lawyer and this is not legal advice)

Comment: @user253751 There is a very important difference between the app being derivative of the dictionary, or the download including the dictionary. The GPL allows GPL and non-GPL works to be distributed together, as long as the recipient's rights are preserved regarding the GPL works. This is fairly clear e.g. when downloading a ZIP file or a Docker image. I would agree that this is far less clear in a mobile app. Also, just because a part is downloaded separately wouldn't mean it's a non-derivative work. This is often suggested as a workaround for GPL libraries, but doesn't work.

Comment: @amon The intent of the "mere aggregation" clause was to allow people to put a bunch of separate program installers onto one CD, some GPL and some not (I used to have several such CDs). This is clearly different to what is happening here. And some clauses from the license: "[mere aggregation applies when works ...] are not by their nature extensions of the covered work, and which are not combined with it such as to form a larger program ..." the FAQ weasels out by saying judges will ultimately decide. In my (non-lawyer) opinion, this combination does form a larger program.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to *sell* the software on Apples App Store you run into a problem: Apples terms and conditions state that any payment made by the customer is not for the software itself, but for the license to use it. But the GPL license states you are not allowed to charge for the license, only for the software. Together, these two terms mean that GPL licensed software on the App Store must be free of any charge.

Comment: According to the FSF, this is incorrect. [Their position](https://www.fsf.org/blogs/licensing/more-about-the-app-store-gpl-enforcement) is that you cannot even distribute GPL software for free on the App Store.  Also, this answer potentially misstates the reasoning: the issue is the imposition of additional restrictions on the licensee.